# CollectionView infinite scroll in Swift with Json parse

Tags: ios, json, swift, collectionview

I wrote the code for collectionView infinite scroll with json parse. Next want to view 20 data each time. After print 20data i will show footer.

Now it is going to view all data in a time. Json parse is ok, also footer view is ok. But the problem is infinite-scroll is not working at all.

Here is my all code:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit


enum LoadMoreStatus{

    case loading
    case finished
    case haveMore
}

class Product: NSObject {

    var id: Int?
    var category_id: Int?
    var image: String?
    var name: String?
    var ar_name: String?

    var ar_description: String?
    var price: NSNumber?
    var quantity: String?
    var is_featured: String?
    var seller_id: String?
    var payment_required: String?
    var is_editors_choice: String?
    var created_at: String?
    var updated_at: String?

}


let categoryCellid = "categoryCellid"

class ProductByCategoryCollectionView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {



    var headercellId = "headercellId"

    var footerCellid = "firstfootercellid"
    var numberOfCells = 5
    var loadingStatus = LoadMoreStatus.haveMore


    var arrProduct = [Product]()
    var category_id:Int = 0;
    var product_count:Int = 0;

    func reloadData(){

        collectionView?.reloadData()
        if numberOfCells > 0 {
            collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func loadMore() {

        if numberOfCells >= arrProduct.count{ // here will show untill 22
            loadingStatus = .finished
            collectionView?.reloadData()
            return
        }



        Timer.schedule(delay: 2) { timer in
            self.numberOfCells += 10
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



       self.getPropductListByCategory()



        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white

        navigationItem.title = "Product"
        navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Sort By", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)



        self.setupHeaderView()




        collectionView?.register(ProductByCategoryCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: categoryCellid)

        collectionView?.register(ProductByCategoryFooterCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: footerCellid)

    }


    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        var text=""
        switch UIDevice.current.orientation{
        case .portrait:
            text="Portrait"
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            text="PortraitUpsideDown"
        case .landscapeLeft:
            text="LandscapeLeft"
        case .landscapeRight:
            text="LandscapeRight"
        default:
            text="Another"
        }
        NSLog("You have moved: \(text)")

        collectionView?.reloadData()

    }



    func showCategoryDetailSegue() {

        let detailcontroller = UIViewController()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailcontroller, animated: true)
    }




    func sortBtnTarget() {

    }


    func filterBtnTarget() {

    }

    let dividedLine: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)
        return view

    }()

    let totalItemLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.text = ""
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        return label
    }()



    let dividerLineView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        return view
    }()



    func setupHeaderView(){


        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.4, alpha: 0.4)



        dividedLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 95, width: view.frame.width, height: 1)
        totalItemLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 55, width: view.frame.width, height: 40)



        view.addSubview(totalItemLabel)

        view.addSubview(dividedLine)


    }



    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


     return arrProduct.count

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if(indexPath.row==arrProduct.count-1){
            if loadingStatus == .haveMore {
                self.perform(#selector(ProductByCategoryCollectionView.loadMore), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
            }
        }



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: categoryCellid, for: indexPath) as! ProductByCategoryCollectionViewCell
        cell.callProductObject4Cell = arrProduct[indexPath.item]



        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 172, height: 300)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(32, 10, 0, 10)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
      layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let controller1 = UICollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: layout)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(controller1, animated: true)

    }
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var footerView:ProductByCategoryFooterCell!


        if (kind ==  UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) && (loadingStatus != .finished){
            footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: footerCellid, for: indexPath) as! ProductByCategoryFooterCell

        }

        return footerView
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

        return (loadingStatus == .finished) ? CGSize.zero : CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)

    }


}




class ProductByCategoryCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var callProductObject4Cell: Product?{
        didSet {
            productLabel.text = callProductObject4Cell?.name



            if let price = callProductObject4Cell?.price {
                //priceLabel.text = "$\(price)"
                priceLabel.text = "\(price) TK"
            } else {
                priceLabel.text = ""
            }




            if let profileImageUrl = callProductObject4Cell?.image {
                productImage.loadImageUsingUrlString(profileImageUrl)
            }


        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupcategoryCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let productImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()

        image.image = UIImage(named: "default")
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.layer.borderWidth = 1
        image.layer.borderColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        image.layer.masksToBounds = true
        return image
    }()

    let productLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "productName"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 10)

        return label
    }()

    let priceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        //        label.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        label.text = ""
        label.textColor = .orange
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13)

        return label
    }()

    func setupcategoryCell() {

        addSubview(productImage)
        addSubview(productLabel)
        addSubview(priceLabel)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: productImage)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(230)]-2-[v1][v2(10)]-5-|", views: productImage,productLabel, priceLabel)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: productLabel)

        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: priceLabel)
    }
}



class ProductByCategoryFooterCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .white
        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let menuHeaderLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "loadin more waiting"
        label.textColor = .green
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    func setupCell() {

        addSubview(menuHeaderLabel)



        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": menuHeaderLabel]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-5-[v0(30)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": menuHeaderLabel]))

    }
}



extension Timer {

    class func schedule(delay: TimeInterval, handler: @escaping (Timer!) -> Void) -> Timer {
        let fireDate = delay + CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        let timer = CFRunLoopTimerCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, fireDate, 0, 0, 0, handler)
        CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), timer, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes)
        return timer!
    }

    class func schedule(repeatInterval interval: TimeInterval, handler: @escaping (Timer!) -> Void) -> Timer {
        let fireDate = interval + CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        let timer = CFRunLoopTimerCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, fireDate, interval, 0, 0, handler)
        CFRunLoopAddTimer(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), timer, CFRunLoopMode.commonModes)
        return timer!
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: i want to just 20 data in a time. this is going to view all data in a time

Comment: check the count of array.

Comment: @Amanpreet please be more details

Comment: @MohammadBashirSidani infinite-scroll is not working

Comment: If you want to show 20 data items in one time... and other 20 times by scrolling collection view. Then for this your web services must return 20 data items for one time and while scrolling you will hit again the web service and it will send other 20 items.

Comment: And for this you have t o you use pagination, In first hit of web service you will send page = 1 and for second it page = 2 and so on. Hope it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum LoadMoreStatus {
    case loading
    case finished
    case haveMore
}

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var verticalDataSource = [String]()

    var firstCellid = "firstcellid"
    var firstFooterCellid = "firstfootercellid"
    var numberOfCells = 5
    var loadingStatus = LoadMoreStatus.haveMore

    func reloadData() {
        //numberOfCells = 10
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        if numberOfCells > 0 {
            collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .left, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func loadMore() {
        if numberOfCells >= 40 { 
            // here will show untill finished number
            loadingStatus = .finished
            collectionView?.reloadData()
            return
        }

        // Replace code with web service and append to data source
        Timer.schedule(delay: 2) { timer in
            self.numberOfCells += 2
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

        collectionView?.register(VerticalCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: firstCellid)
        collectionView?.register(VerticalCollectionViewCell2.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: firstFooterCellid)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK - Rotation methods

    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        var text=""

        switch UIDevice.current.orientation {
        case .portrait:
            text="Portrait"
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            text="PortraitUpsideDown"
        case .landscapeLeft:
            text="LandscapeLeft"
        case .landscapeRight:
            text="LandscapeRight"
        default:
            text="Another"
        }

        NSLog("You have moved: \(text)")

        collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfCells
    }

    // The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if(indexPath.row==numberOfCells-1) {
            if loadingStatus == .haveMore {
                self.perform(#selector(ViewController.loadMore), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)
            }
        }       

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: firstCellid, for: indexPath) as! VerticalCollectionViewCell
        cell.menuHeaderLabel.text = "Labet text no \(indexPath.item)"
        return cell

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var footerView:VerticalCollectionViewCell2!

        if (kind ==  UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) && (loadingStatus != .finished) {
            footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: firstFooterCellid, for: indexPath) as! VerticalCollectionViewCell2
        }

        return footerView
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return (loadingStatus == .finished) ? CGSize.zero : CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    }        
}

class VerticalCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let menuHeaderLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "lable text"
        label.textColor = .orange
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    func setupCell() {
        addSubview(menuHeaderLabel)

        // addTaskButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MenuHeader.addTask), for: .touchUpInside)

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": menuHeaderLabel]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-5-[v0(30)]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": menuHeaderLabel]))
    }
}
```

Comment: what shall we refine our loadMore module to support infinite scrolling both up and down directions?